# call of overloaded 'write(int)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, arduino

Right now, i am trying to print a special character to my LCD screen. for some reason- this message appears: *call of overloaded 'write(int)' is ambiguous*

I have no idea what this means, and help would be great.

Code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

byte customChar[] = {
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B00100,
  B01110,
  B10101,
  B00100,
  B01010
};


void setup() {
  
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.createChar(0, customChar);
  lcd.home();
  lcd.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  for(int position = 0; position < 13; position++) {
  lcd.scrollDisplayRight();
  delay(150);

  int state = digitalRead(8);
  if (state != 0) {
    if (state == HIGH) {

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Hello!");
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new to coding so i cant tell the difference. I'm using the arduino.. so c++

Comment: Is there more to the error such as which candidates were considered?

Comment: Nope, there wasn't anything else in the error.

Comment: That's because it is specting a character, and 0 is reserved as end-of-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiquidCrystal is a subclass of Print which has two `write()` methods:
`virtual size_t write(uint8_t);` and  `size_t write(const char *str)`. With a parameter of 0 either of those could be called hence it is ambiguous.

Try casting to the type you want: `write(static_cast<uint8_t>(0))`